# Router and multiples outlets

Tags: angular, router

I working in a new project with Angular 2 and have a single question, and I need a suggestion.
I need a sidenav, where your content differs according to a route (secondary router).

By example:
   I have a principal route, one list of person, and each time click over person, some information about person is displayed in sidenav.
   If i define the dom structure the following way (app.component), this throw a error.

```
<md-sidenav-layout fullscreen>
  <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side">
    <md-nav-list>
      <a md-list-item>
        <md-icon md-list-icon></md-icon>
        <span md-line></span>
        <span md-line class="desc"></span>
      </a>
      <a md-list-item>
        <md-icon md-list-icon></md-icon>
        <span md-line></span>
        <span md-line class="desc"></span>
      </a>
    </md-nav-list>
  </md-sidenav>

  <md-toolbar color="primary">

    <div style="flex:1">
      <button md-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
        <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
      </button>
      <span>---</span>
    </div>

    <button md-icon-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="account">
      <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
    </button>

    <md-menu #account="mdMenu">
      <button md-menu-item>
        <md-icon>settings</md-icon>
        <span>Settings</span>
      </button>
      <button md-menu-item>
        <md-icon>help</md-icon>
        <span>Help</span>
      </button>
      <button md-menu-item>
        <md-icon>logout</md-icon>
        <span>Logout</span>
      </button>
    </md-menu>
  </md-toolbar>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  <md-sidenav  #sidenavInfo align="end" mode="side">
    <router-outlet name="info"></router-outlet>
  </md-sidenav>

</md-sidenav-layout>
```

And the router definition is:

```
export const ContactsAppRoutes = [
    { path: '',   redirectTo: '/planos', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'viewer/:id', component: ViewerComponent },
    { path: 'planos', component: AgendaComponent },
    { path: 'planos/:id', outlet: 'info', component: AgendaDetailsComponent }
]
```

I see severals examples about multiples outlets, by example:

- https://github.com/onehungrymind/ng2-named-router-outlets

I see in this project, that two "outlets" are in the same dom level, underneath the parent component, is this a restrictions?, or I can define outlets in any place of DOM structure and link this of any component whitout distintion.

Any idea?

Update:

When from the component: "AgendaComponent", I want to navigate to the details "AgendaDetailsComponent"

```
this.router.navigate (['planos', {outlets: {'info': [p.id]}}]);
```

The error is:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'planos'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'planos'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:109231:16) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:109200:29) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:55124:31) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:471:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:445:18) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:471:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:445:18) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:471:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:445:18) [angular]
    at LastSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:471:26) [angular]
    at LastSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:445:18) [angular]
    at MergeAllSubscriber.OuterSubscriber.notifyError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:850:26) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:115294:21) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:445:18) [angular]
```

Comment: Why not an service? In your component you call your service that change the sidenav links?

Comment: I have a service that open or close the sidenav, but, I believe that content in sidenav is responsibility of component (sub router), that is navigated. You have an example?

Comment: The responsability of a service is to etablish a communication between two components. In this case your content component and your sidenav so maybe its an acceptable way. I have no example for the moment it was just an idea.

Comment: What error is being thrown?

Comment: I updated the question with the error...